# Алгоритм генерации случайных чисел на делфи

Tags: delphi, случайные-числа

Генерирую символы из диапазона a-z(26 штук). Начинаю генерацию с 1 символа, запомнил количество символов len:=1. Случайно генерирую символ, сверяю его и если он есть генерирую другой. Все символы есть необходимо сгенерировать уже по 2 символа от aa до az(26 штук) - потом ba-bz,ca-cz и т.д. до za-zz. Потом уже по 3 символа - aaa-aaz(26 штук),aaa-abz,aaa-aaa-acz и т.д до zzy-zzz. Далее по 4 символа aaaa-zzzz.

Какой для этого использовать алгоритм подскажите?

Comment: Я бы заполнил массив всеми нужными вариантами, а потом перемешал.

Comment: Эм... Число в системе счисления по основанию 26? Был где-то вопрос такойже

Comment: 26 это 26 символов английского алфавита от a до z

Comment: что не мешает рассмотреть их как число в 26СС

Answer (score 1):

***Ответ для более общего случая, когда порядок следования элементов не важен, а важна только группировка по 1-2-3-4 знакоместа***

1.1 Создаете массив из 26 элементов
1.2. Заполняете значениями от 0 до 25
1.3. Перемешиваете в нем элементы (меняете местами случайные пары, например 26 раз)
1.4. Преобразуете значение в букву `:= Char(Ord('A') + element[I])`
1.5. Вот вам первые 26 элементов от A до Z в случайном порядке без повторов.

2.1. Создаете массив из 26*26 элементов
2.2. Заполняете значениями от 0 до 26*26-1
2.3. Перемешиваете в нем элементы (меняете местами случайные пары, например 26*26 раз)
2.4. Преобразуете значение в букву `:= Char(Ord('A') + element[I] div 26) + Char(Ord('A') + element[I] mod 26)`
2.5. Вот вам вторые 26*26 элементов от AA до ZZ в случайном порядке без повторов.

3.1 Аналогично, 17576 элементов

4.1 Аналогично, 456976 элементов

На первом этапе решение выглядит несколько медленнее - особенно перемешивание 460 тысячного массива, но результат будет гораздо быстрее в итоге, т.к. вам не придется проверять, что каждый случайный элемент используется только 1 раз (сравнивая 450 тысячный элемент со всеми 449 999 предыдущими и повторяя генерацию и сравнение, если он уже использовался)

Answer (score 0):

***Ответ для конкретного условия вашей задачи***

1.1 Создаете массив из 26 элементов
1.2. Заполняете значениями от 0 до 25
1.3. Перемешиваете в нем элементы (меняете местами случайные пары, например 26 раз)
1.4. Преобразуете значение в букву `:= Char(Ord('A') + element[I])`
1.5. Вот вам первые 26 элементов от A до Z в случайном порядке без повторов.

Далее, для получения AA..AZ повторяете шаг 1.3 (повторное случайное перемешивание даст новый случайный набор) и выводите результат как `:= 'A' + Char(Ord('A') + element[I])`. Далее повторяете шаг 1.3 и `:= 'B' + Char(Ord('A') + element[I])`. Думаю алгоритм ясен.